# Class Not Registered, Exception REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I get this error on create new instance of `CRAXDDRT.ApplicationClass
 CRAXDDRT.ApplicationClass crApplication = new ApplicationClass();`

Retrieving the `COM` class factory for component with `CLSID {D260B86E-0D8C-4008-B87B-3E6D6BA69A9F}` failed due to the following error:

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I change `targetframework` to `x86` but error do not solved.

IDE is Visual studio 2015 and `Interop.CRAXDDRT` is `11.5.0.0` version 
I install `CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_12` and `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12`.

Is there any help for this issue?